# Getting "The system cannot find the file specified" while opening IE browser in TOSCA

Tags: tosca

I am new to TOSCA ,trying to open IE browser and closing it However in Scratch Book is showing above error in log info.I checked Test Configuration is correctly set as Browser InternetExplorer. Could anyone please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the Windows path variable contains the directory where windows can find iexplore.exe. If not then alter your path

Answer (score -1):

You can speciefy a tesconiguration parameter with Value.
The purpule one, named Broser and the value is InternetExplorer.

https://documentation.tricentis.com/en/1030/content/tbox/xbrowser.htm

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer instead of linking to external sources. For example, what do you mean by "tesconiguration"?